How to publish a Go package/module without publishing a git repo?
I want to publish a collection of go packages as 'my.domain.tld/something'
Can I do it without running a git server on my domain? For example, can I just publish zip files and metadata at the domain name and have the go tools work with it?
I can't find documentation about how to do it.

These are known as vanity import paths. You can setup my.domain.tld/something to serve an HTML webpage with a go-import meta tag which points to the location the code is hosted.
The format is: <meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix vcs repo-root">
For example, you could instruct Go to fetch the code from a Github repository using something like
<meta name="go-import" content="my.domain.tld/something git github.com/myusername/myproject">

Some links:

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths

https://sagikazarmark.hu/blog/vanity-import-paths-in-go/


